# Convert QWERTY barcode scanner input to AZERTY

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner, azerty-keyboard

I'm trying to scan barcodes and send them to an input field.

I have a Barcode scanner (Symbol LS2208) but when I scan a barcode I get the code as if it was written using a QWERTY keyboard (instead of the AZERTY keyboard my users have), for example, instead of getting `2` I get `é`, `?` instead of `M`, etc.

I read its manual but didn't find how to change the language, so I would like to convert the text using javascript in the input onkey event.

I wonder if there is an existing script that would convert QWERTY keys to AZERTY.

Comment: The key here is the match between scanner and OS.  if you can't find the way to configure azerty on the scanner, configure qwerty on PC keyboard

Comment: the Barcode Scanner is recognized has a keyboard, try to change its layout into the localization options in windows

Comment: @LuisSiquot 99% of our visitors use AZERTY keyboards , I dont want ask them to configure QWERTY on their PC keyboars .

Comment: @ArnaudGueras do you mean change it in the region an Language windows ?

Comment: @stacker, if my answer helped you, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the LS2208 manual, go to page B-10. Scan the "French (France)" barcode (or other appropriate barcode if you use a different type of keyboard).

You can find the manual here:
https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/LS2208_US-EN

Comment: Thanks thats helped me

Comment: @stacker, feel free to up vote and/or accept the question if it did!

Comment: Done , but I dont have the right to vote yet :D

Comment: this dont work with library suck node-hid (nodejs)